# How to set local JSON data into functional components in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react. I got stucked here. I'm not sure how to pass json data that is getting returned as function to useState.I used classes and everything worked perfectly fine. Now i'm trying to convert that code into functional components. When I delete an item it displays an error. movie.filter is not a function.

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component,useState } from 'react'
import {getMovies} from "../services/fakeMovieService"

function Movies() {
    const movies = getMovies()
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState(movies);

    const handleDelete = (movie) => {
      const newM=  movie.filter(m => m._id != movie._id)
      setMovie({newM})
    }
return (
               <React.Fragment>
            <table className="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                {movie.map(movie =>(
                    <tr key={movie._id}>
                        <td>{movie.title}</td>
                        <td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
                        <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
                        <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
                    <td><button onClick={()=>handleDelete(movie)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
                ))
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default Movies;
```

**JSON**

```
import * as genresAPI from "./fakeGenreService";

const movies = [
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471815",
    title: "Terminator",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 6,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5,
    publishDate: "2018-01-03T19:04:28.809Z"
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471816",
    title: "Die Hard",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 5,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471817",
    title: "Get Out",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
    numberInStock: 8,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471819",
    title: "Trip to Italy",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181a",
    title: "Airplane",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181b",
    title: "Wedding Crashers",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181e",
    title: "Gone Girl",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 4.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181f",
    title: "The Sixth Sense",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
    numberInStock: 4,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471821",
    title: "The Avengers",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  }
];

export function getMovies() {
  return movies;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setMovie({newM})
```

should be

```
setMovie(newM)
```

because your state is an array. The argument `movie` and state `movie` have the same name so you're trying to use `Array.prototype.filter` on an object.

Rename the restructured array values of `useState` to `movies` and `setMovies`:

```
const initialMovies = getMovies()
const [movies, setMovies] = useState(initialMovies);
```

Use functional state update as the new state depends on the old state:

```
const handleDelete = (movie) => {
    setMovies(previousMovies => previousMovies.filter(m => m._id !== movie._id))
}
```

and use `movies` to render

```
{movies.map(movie => (...
```